# How to Delay js function after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a delay after clicking a button to get some data.
The script is run inside the browser console.

*$(pages()) get's the pagination buttons.*

```
  let calls = [];  
  for (let i = 1; i <= callPagesCount; i++) {
    $(pages()).find('a')[i].click()

    setTimeout(() => {}, 200)

    // Call the below, 200 ms later
    callsNode().map((i, el) => {
      calls.push({
        call_condition: $(el).find('div > span').text().trim(),
        date: $(el).find('div').text().trim().match(/\[(.+)\]/i),
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: I think you just want to put that `callsNode().map...` inside the curly braces of the `setTimeout`. That way it will be executed after 200ms.

Comment: Do you mean, click the button, it will execute something in the server, then after some time to show the return data in the browser?   Otherwise what is the difference between wait and not wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map()`, `.delay()`, `.queue()`, `.promise()`

```js
$(() => {
  $("a").on("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked")
  });

  $({}).queue("pages"
  , $.map($("a") /* Array.from({length:callPagesCount}, (_, i) => i + 1) */ 
  , (el, i) =>
    (next) => {
      el.click();
      /*
      $(pages()).find('a')[i].click()
      */
      $({}).delay(1000 /* 200 */ , "delay")
        .queue(_next => {
          /*
          callsNode().map((i, el) => {
            calls.push({
              call_condition: $(el).find('div > span').text().trim(),
              date: $(el).find('div').text().trim().match(/\[(.+)\]/i),
            })
          })
          */
          _next();
        }).dequeue("delay")
        .promise("delay").then(next)
    }
  )).dequeue("pages");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a href="">a</a>
<a href="">b</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to delay in JavaScript is to use the setTimeout function.

```
setTimeout((() => {
    // do something after a delay
}), 200);
```

Change `200` to the time you want to wait in milliseconds.

In your case, it looks like you want to put `callNodes.map()...` inside the setTimeout:

```
  let calls = [];  
  for (let i = 1; i <= callPagesCount; i++) {
    $(pages()).find('a')[i].click()

    setTimeout((() => {
        // Call the below, 200 ms later
        callsNode().map((i, el) => {
          calls.push({
            call_condition: $(el).find('div > span').text().trim(),
            date: $(el).find('div').text().trim().match(/\[(.+)\]/i),
          })
        })
    }), 200);


  }
```

Comment: Yes, but setTimeout keeps it's own context, how to push to *calls array*?

Comment: I don't think I understand—you'd still be pushing to the `calls` array.